# Is there any 'web-based' sql test environment?

Tags: sql, database

In HTML+CSS+JS world, http://jsfiddle.net/ is very helpful tool for asking / making example about web development. And I also saw several browser(javascript)-based programming language compilers and REPLs. But I can't find online / web-based test environment for database operations( especially for RDBMS ).

Is there any open/free database service with web-based interfaces for testing queries?

---

Added: This tool will be good for this situation; If I'm troubling with complex queries, then create a sample table via web interface and ask it on stackoverflow with the 'sample table URL'. Anyone can access to the URL and test their queries on web site. (Yes, queries are running on 'real' database system) And also the query results can be tracked, then we can even make 'ranking' for it :)

Comment: Make one and market it like jsfiddle.net.  You could probably make money by getting the database vendors involved to provide their systems to you for inclusion plus having ads.

Comment: @ChrisLively: Agreed - the computing power required for such a project scares me though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

You can try your SQL query and execute/test it.

Comment: Thanks for the plug! SQL Fiddle is my site, and I think this question was one of the ones I had read which inspired me to create it (the timing certainly fits - I started in mid January).

Comment: Wow, sorry to @AlixAxel - former accepted answerer, but a Big step of JakeFeasel's makes me to change the accepted answer. Nice work!

Answer (score 6):

There are free "disposable" database servers like [db4free](http://www.db4free.net/) and even [MonoQL](http://demo.monoql.com/).

As far as the web-based interfaces and short URLs go, I don't think you'll have much luck.

To manage your data you have to stick to what is provided (usually phpMyAdmin or similar) and there is no short-URL to query mapping. One other caveat of such system is that (without the appropriate user permissions) one user could easily destroy all your test data -- and remember that (relational) database versioning is much more expensive than plain text versioning, so that's pretty much out of the question.

For non-RDBMS, I can think of [try.mongodb.org](http://try.mongodb.org/) -- but it suffers from the same problems.

Almost forgot, the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), lets you practice T-SQL queries (with permalinks).

---

**PS:** As a personal side-note, I think it's a cool idea and I would love to see something like that implemented, perhaps even mashed-up with [SchemaBank](http://schemabank.com/) or similar - that would be just awesome.

Comment: Thanks Alix! Stack exchange data explorer could be a sample that i imagined. Awesome stackexchange team!

Answer (score 2):

You can't really test a query without the right underlying dbms, schemas (or databases), tables, constraints, stored procedures, and permissions, which tend to be highly application specific. (That is, not readily reusable among multiple users.)

Instead, the database world has grown up into database management systems that you can freely download and install locally.  Then you can build and populate your own tables, and test your queries however you like.

Most of these come with both a command line interface and some kind of graphical interface. It's not clear to me what a web-based interface would give you that doesn't already exist in one form or another.

I think that, to do what you want, would require commercial licenses for Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, and Sybase.  That's a pretty high barrier to entry for a free web site.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, I agree with the meaning and purpose of 'formal' database systems. However, I'm asking about a convenient and easy-to-access ad-hoc database system. With jsfiddle, we can't make any commercial or large-scale site. But it is absolutely useful platform for ad-hoc test for web development. I'm finding something like that in database era.

Comment: @Catcall - have you seen my site sqlfiddle.com? I was able to roll this out using the free versions of SQL Server and Oracle (no support for DB2 yet, but there is a free version of that too that I plan on using eventually).

Comment: @JakeFeasel: Yes, I've seen it. To me, it looks like a clear violation of [your license agreement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html) with Oracle: "[You may not] make the programs available in any manner to any third party;". I don't know about the others. (shrug)

Comment: @JakeFeasel I had not, but now I have, also, come to [dba.se] please. :D I think we're going to adopt you/annoy the crap out of you :D

Comment: Technically @Catcall he's only giving access to a development environment, not to the applications. He has to provide a translation layer for everything that happens, including potential retokenization of all elements, so there's no actual direct interface between the user and the software, merely what appears to be an Oracle database/instance/whatever-they-call-it.

Comment: @Catcall - I don't think I'm actually in violation of that agreement.  I'm not really doing much beyond what any other web developer (who is using Oracle 11g R2 XE as a backend) would be doing.  I'm just letting other people define the queries I'm executing.  "Make available" to me sounds more like "distribute the binaries", which of course I'm not doing.

Comment: @jcolebrand I've got an account over there - in fact, I've asked a few questions there that were directly used as part of my development effort for sqlfiddle.  I should spend more time hanging out there... perhaps I will!

Answer (score 1):

Trouble with a web based query analyser is that you'd need to let it 'tunnel' on to your box to run the queries and for many making a development/test box open to the internet is not a possibility.

For a non web based tool you could look at LinqPad http://www.linqpad.net/ - it does Linq & Sql and other stuff too - very handy tool indeed

Comment: I disagree.  For simple things it might be perfect.